# What language/API to use for a standalone live-input audio visualizer app?

Tags: objective-c, actionscript-3, air, audio

I develop with Actionscript and was glad to see that AIR 2.0 was going to give access to mic input data. I planned to use this to create a visualizer set to the tempo of the incoming live audio. After doing a few days of google research it seems unlikely that it will be possible to analyze the data of the mic input in Flash/AIR. If anyone has ideas on how I can achieve this in AIR please let me know. (I'm open to workarounds.)

That being said, I don't want to give up on the idea so I'm interested in suggestions for other language/API to use. My requirements for the app are:

- Run on OSX
- Two windows - one that can go fullscreen while the other(controller GUI) stays put
- Able to access live mic input data

I've done reading on FFT and understand what needs to be done on the sound side so no need to help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [Processing](http://www.processing.org/).

It's a great language (it's java but with a lot of "help") and a very logical next step after programming in Actionscript. Processing has a great and helpful community and there are many tutorials and libraries available.

I've seen several processing applications which do what you describe. Most can be found on the [openprocessing](http://www.openprocessing.org/) site or in the [exhibition](http://www.processing.org/exhibition/) section.

Also see the [available sound libraries](http://www.processing.org/reference/libraries/#sound).

From the processing site:

> Processing is a programming language,
>   development environment, and online
>   community that since 2001 has promoted
>   software literacy within the visual
>   arts. Initially created to serve as a
>   software sketchbook and to teach
>   fundamentals of computer programming
>   within a visual context, Processing
>   quickly developed into a tool for
>   creating finished professional work as
>   well.

If you want to give it a quick glance, just download it and open and run the bundled examples.